# Migration to Linux. Files readability. File systems

Tags: windows-7, files, system, migration

My idea is the following:

I want to migrate from win7 to Linux, specifically Ubuntu. As I know the file systems of the two OS are different - NTFS and the Linux one I don't know...

I want to put my files from my current HDD to another, then to install the Ubuntu and finally to get the files back.

Will it be possible the files (which come from the old file system) to be read by the new file system? 
Also, what kind of obstacles I should have in mind when trying to do that?

I am more than beginner in the Linux world so every additional advice will be highly appreciated! 
I have never used Linux but I believe it is the proper way of using a computer!

I will keep my words about Microsoft.... :X

Thank you, people!!!

Comment: Have you already tried to boot Linux from a LiveCD, LiveDVD or LiveUSB? You can easily test if you can read and write your files on disk from there. Also I recommend to install Ubuntu along-side your current installation, to try it out for some time.

Comment: Hi, MadMike! The problem is that when I tried to install Ubuntu, the installation read my hard drive as one piece while I have about 4 or 5 pieces. I have 1TB HDD which is divided in about 4-5 parts... So my first obstacle was to install Ubuntu on the hard drive. That is why I want to keep my files aside for some time, to format the hard with the Ubutu file system (ext4), to install it on it, and then to put my files back. Does it sounds logic???

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can read NTFS partitions. My recommendation is to use an external USB enclosure for your old hard drive. After installing Ubuntu, just attach the enclosure into your computer and you can now transfer the files you want from the external drive.

I recommend you to use ext4 for your Ubuntu filesystem.

Comment: Hi, Justin! When I wanted to install Ubuntu, it really read my NTFS HDD but as a one whole drive, not the different partitions which I actually have. Also, what do you mean by "external USB enclosure for hard drive"? Did you mean external USB HDD?

Answer (score 0):

> and the Linux one I don't know...

Ubuntu file system is [ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). Version 4 even (`ext4`).

> Will it be possible the files (which come from the old file system) to be read by the new file system?

Yes, if they are documents that is. 2 examples: LibreOffices Writer handles most of the files you can create with Word. LibreOffice Calc can handle Excel files. Plain text will never be a problem. But for a complete answer you need to tell us what files you have ;)

> Also, what kind of obstacles I should have in mind when trying to do that?

You do need to pay attention to macro's. These will not work and need to be re-created since they are created (mainly/solely?) with Visual Basic and LibreOffice you can use Python to create macro's.

Comment: Hi, Rinzwind! Thanks for the valuable information! What I have is documents (word, excel), video files (movies and video clips), mp3s, pics, all of the usual suspects... :) The question is that they are written under the NTFS and I am not sure whether they will be read by the ext4. Because, I have the files written firstly in NTFS, then moved to other NTFS (while I would be able to migrate to Linux), and then transferred to ext4... As I know from friends of mine, they use some additional software for Linux to read their NTFS files... Your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Tonka that does all not matter.